# Windows command to restart the computer with user consent

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I am working on a LabVIEW application and built an installer out of it. I need to restart the computer with the user consent after installing the application. At the moment, I am running a batch file automatically after installation that restarts the computer without an option for the user to abort it.

I am using the following command: `shutdown /r`. This command restarts the computer after a minute.

Is there a way to open the restart computer window with options "Restart Now", "Restart Later" and "Cancel" so that the user can decide what should happen next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [PsShutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) which has a `-c` option that allows the user to cancel the shutdown:

[image]

---

Since you say you are using a batch file, you could also ask the user on the command line if they want to restart using [choice](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html):

```
CHOICE /m Restart
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 goto NO_RESTART

PsShutdown -c <OTHER ARGS>

:NO_RESTART
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try and see if it works.